# How to combine all recursive csv file in 1 csv

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a long directory with 152000 CSV files.

```
 find . -name "*.csv. | wc -l"
152000
```

By this I got list `find . -name "*.csv"`

```
./2015/2015-121/foo.csv
./2015/2015-19/Z00.csv
./2015/20888-/woo.csv
./2015/20xx.csv
./2015/foo.csv
.
.
.
and so on
```

Most of the files have same name like the zoo or woo

I was trying to add all files in 1 directory and then run command

```
cat `ls -v | grep .csv` > final.csv
```

So i do like

```
 mv ./2015-09/woo.csv ../2015/
 mv ./2015-01/woo.csv ../2015/
 mv ./2015-02/zoo.csv ../2015/
.
.
.
.
and so on
```

but it replaces old woo.csv to. new woo.csv

Any way I can add then 1 file like final.csv

or

Any possible way I can add all files in 1 directory so new woo.csv not replace old woo.csv

Comment: Hello! I ask you kindly to put more effort in making your question clear. There are many small errors that, combined, just make our life harder. For example, `find . -name "*.csv. | wc -l"`, "zoo or woo", it would just seem that you typed that in a hurry and dumped it to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `find` command:

```
find . -name "*.csv" -exec cat {} + > /tmp/final.csv
```

Comment: I google a little bit... couldn't get meaning of `-exec cat {}` , I. run this command its. in process... can you help me to udnerstand whatit does `-exec cat {}`

Comment: `-exec` is an option in `find` that runs a given command. `{}` is placeholder for each entry found by `find` command and `+` is command terminator that allows processing multiple files at a time. Did you get your expected output using this command?

Comment: Something wring in logical.. its not stopping.. file size is keep inceasing for last few hours...

Comment: Make sure final.csv is outside the directory from where find is running